# sizeof() not giving same size as compiler layout switch?

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, struct, sizeof

I am using the Microsoft C++ compiler (2012) with the `-d1reportallclasslayout` switch to show class layout. This is my class:

```
class O{
    shared_ptr<A> a;
    shared_ptr<B> b;
    std::string c;
    std::vector<double> d;
    std::vector<X> e;
    int f;
};

class Y : public O{
    int g;
};
```

and when I use `-d1reportallclasslayout` it gives me the following:

```
1>  class Y size(136):
1>      +---
1>      | +--- (base class O)
1>   0  | | {vfptr}
1>   8  | | ?$shared_ptr@VA@@ a
1>  24  | | ?$shared_ptr@VB@@ b
1>  40  | | ?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@ c
1>  72  | | ?$vector@NV?$allocator@N@std@@ d
1>  96  | | ?$vector@V?$shared_ptr@VX@@@boost@@V?$allocator@V?$shared_ptr@VX@@@boost@@@std@@ e
1>  120 | | f
1>      | | <alignment member> (size=4)
1>      | +---
1>  128 | g
1>      +---
```

So the above says vectors `d` and `e` are both 24 bytes (96-72 and 120-96). However, when I use `sizeof()` (in debug mode) I get 32 for each vector:

```
std::cout << sizeof(my_Y_instance->d) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(my_Y_instance->e) << std::endl;
```

I know vector has three pointer class members (hence 24 bytes)- but I cant understand if `sizeof()` is including padding, why isn't the class layout showing this padding?

Now I genuinely don't know whether its occupying 24 or 32 bytes of the object?

Comment: After creating such an object `y`, output the address of the according members `cout << static_cast<void*>(&y.d) << ' ' << static_cast<void*>(&y.e) << endl;`. I wonder what that will give you. Further, what is `sizeof y` then? In any case, I understand why you are puzzled, this doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: There is something else going on.  Padding wouldn't make it 32 bytes from 24 bytes.  24 is already at 8 byte boundary.

Comment: I wonder if anyone with access to MSVC can reproduce this?

Comment: I forgot the data member of Y (just added it), but it follows the vectors so shouldn't affect the answer.

Comment: In gcc 4.8.3, the sizeof is 24, as well as the difference in memory positions

Comment: tried it.  in debug build everything is consistently 32.  in release build everything is consistently 24.  why don't you try clean and rebuild.

Comment: There is something you're not telling us, or your output is stale.  Your code says "std::vector<X> e;", but the class report suggests that that line should be  "std::vector<shared_ptr<X>> e;".  The class reports that there are some virtual functions, but your code doesn't have any virtual functions.  Seems there is an inconsistency between the code you're showing us and the code that you used to generate the output.

Comment: @thang think you're right. the build configuration for the switch was different.

Comment: Why do so many people doubt or disbelieve what `sizeof()` returns?  It is what it is.

Comment: @user This is what I told you in my answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I don't think it's debug vs release.  It's that the code used in /d1reportallclasslayout is different than the code that's being run.

Comment: @thang So you don't think that those members are vectors?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, see my previous long comment.  There's a clear mismatch.

Comment: @thang size of vector doesn't change because of that, or does it? It is tough to be expected to debug that which we cannot see.

Comment: @DavidHefferman, maybe, maybe not, but what it does show is that the code that is being compiled is different from the one that is run.  It's not clear that his workspace has a debug and a release build configuration.  Who knows how the compiler flags have been mucked up.

Comment: I think that @thang has raised some valid concerns about the code. I'd like to add another thing, which should actually not be necessary to ask for, and that is the so-called minimal example. In particular, `A`, `B`, and `X` are missing and I wonder if their definition matters at all and whether using some builtin-type doesn't give the same effect. Also, there is no reason for a vtable pointer, so either that compiler output is misleading or it's not from the shown code.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you use the debug runtime for one output and the release runtime for the other.

```
std::cout << sizeof(std::vector<int>) << endl;
```

outputs 24 for x64/release and 32 for x64/debug.

Comment: Nah when I print out the sizeof() thats debug too.

Comment: I suggest you go back again and look more closely.